# Is there somewhere I can buy or bid on the whole Ragnarok Into the Abyss manga series?

Tags: merchandise, ragnarok-into-the-abyss

I remember that this is a manga with 7 chapters or books about the servers of the former Ragnarok online (if I'm not mistaken: Chaos, Iris, Loki, Fenris, Fenrir etc.).

Do you have any suggestions about where I can buy, bid on, or otherwise obtain this manga series?

Comment: In what country/language are you looking to get them from? The series is on indefinite hiatus.

Comment: anything that is english would do.. thanks for asking :)

Comment: Tokyopop, the original NA publisher went out of business, but you can find copies usually second-hand on ebay or Australian copies from Madman Entertainment.

Comment: Gee Thanks for your suggestion . I want to finish reading this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series is currently on on indefinite hiatus. In total there should be 10 volumes. The NA publisher Tokyopop went out of business, but you can probably still get the English version thru Madman Entertainment (UK/AU) or Chuang Yi (Singapore). You might also be able to find used copies on Ebay and other auction sites.